What scripts you can access from the sheets assignScript() function
I was wondering what the limitations are to the scripts you can access from the sheets assignScript() function?
My current code layout is as follows:
function mainCode(){
    copyURL = copySheet(templateURL,destinationFolderID, copyName)
    images = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(copyURL).getSheetByName(sheetName).getImages()
    images[0].assignScript("scriptToBeAssigned")
}

function scriptToBeAssigned(){
    // another script here that I want to assign to the image in the sheet copy I've made
}

Both of the above functions are bounded to the same spreadsheet (not the copy that is being made, a different one). Currently, after assigning the script, I keep getting an error message when I click on the image saying the script function could not be found. I thought that maybe I was getting that error because it's bounded to my other spreadsheet. I then tried copying the scriptToBeAssigned() to my function library and assigning it that way but had the same error message pop up. Is there a work around to this? Can I assign a library script or a script bounded to another spreadsheet via assignScript()?

Although I'm not sure about your whole script, about copySheet(templateURL,destinationFolderID, copyName), if your showing script is put into a Google Spreadsheet and copy the Spreadsheet, the copied Spreadsheet has the same script as the original Spreadsheet. I thought that this might be close to your expected result. But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand not the copy that is being made, a different one. So, if that is different from your actual situation, can I ask you about the details of your current situation?

script needs to be authorized in every copy of your spreadsheet - you can't skip this step if that's what you are asking

@player0 that was what I was asking, I did skirt around authorizing it for another script. For the other one in my main spreadsheet script I had a separate function that I tied to the copied spreadsheet by using an installable onEdit() trigger. I then didn't have to authorize the script every time I copied the spreadsheet. I was hoping I could do the same here.

@Tanaike OP wants to use assignScript to assign a function(scriptToBeAssigned) in one bound  spreadsheet(say SpreadsheetA) to another spreadsheet(Copy of SpreadsheetA).

then tried copying the scriptToBeAssigned() to my function library and assigning it that way Could you give sample code for this to explain this better? If this is a actual library, the assignScript should assign it like library.scriptToBeAssigned

@Tanaike, TheMaster is correct, sorry I wasn't super clear! But just for clarity, the other spreadsheet isn't a copy of SpreadsheetA, it's a copy of a different spreadsheet (say SpreadsheetB)

@TheMaster I tried that, my library is called FunctionLibrary so I did assignScript("FunctionLibrary.scriptToBeAssigned"). It came up with the same error. I made sure that FunctionLibrary was added to the copied spreadsheet too so it knew what I was referencing.

@TheMaster Thank you for replying. About @Tanaike OP wants to use assignScript to assign a function(scriptToBeAssigned) in one bound spreadsheet(say SpreadsheetA) to another spreadsheet(Copy of SpreadsheetA)., I thought that OP copies the Spreadsheet including the showing script, and wants to use scriptToBeAssigned by executing mainCode of the copied Spreadsheet. But, it seems that my understanding was not correct.

@AnonymousTurtle Thank you for replying. About @Tanaike, TheMaster is correct, sorry I wasn't super clear! But just for clarity, the other spreadsheet isn't a copy of SpreadsheetA, it's a copy of a different spreadsheet (say SpreadsheetB), in this case, the copied Spreadsheet has no script. Under this condition, you want to assign scriptToBeAssigned of the original Spreadsheet to the button on the copied Spreadsheet by executing mainCode of the original one. Is my understanding correct?

From the discussions in the comment, I understood your expected result as follows.

You have 2 Google Spreadsheets like Spreadsheet "A" and Spreadsheet "B".
Spreadsheet "A" has your showing script.
Spreadsheet "B" has no script and an image is put into a sheet.
You want to copy Spreadsheet "B" and assign the function scriptToBeAssigned of Spreadsheet "A" to a button on the copied Spreadsheet "B".
You want to execute the function scriptToBeAssigned by clicking the button on the copied Spreadsheet "B".

Issue and workarounds:
In the current stage, unfortunately, when a function is assigned to a button on the Spreadsheet, the script of the function of the function name is required to be included in the container-bound script of the same Spreadsheet. By the current specification, unfortunately, your goal cannot be directly achieved.
But, I think that in this case, the following 2 workarounds might be able to achieve your expected result So, in this answer, I would like to do the following 2 workarounds.
Pattern 1:
In this pattern, your goal is achieved by manually putting the script of scriptToBeAssigned to Spreadsheet "B". The scenario is as follows.

Open the script editor of Spreadsheet "B" before you copy it, and copy and paste the script of scriptToBeAssigned to the opened script editor and save the script.
Copy the Spreadsheet "B".
Run mainCode from Spreadsheet "A". By this, scriptToBeAssigned is assigned to the button on the copied Spreadsheet "B".

In this scenario, when the button on the copied Spreadsheet "B", the function scriptToBeAssigned of the container-bound script of the copied Spreadsheet "B" can be correctly run.
Additional information:
Here, when you want to change the script of scriptToBeAssigned and want to reflect the latest script by modifying it, you can use the library. In this case, as a simple method, please deploy the script of the Spreadsheet "A" as a library (the identification is Lib). And, please manually copy the following script to the Spreadsheet "B" as the developer mode (HEAD). By this, when you modify scriptToBeAssigned on Spreadsheet "A", the modified script is reflected in the script of Spreadsheet "B".
function scriptToBeAssigned() {
  Lib.scriptToBeAssigned();
}

Pattern 2:
In this pattern, when you cannot manually put the script of scriptToBeAssigned to the Spreadsheet "B", the above scenario can be run by Google Apps Script API. The required steps are as follows.
But, I guess that pattern 1 might be simpler than that pattern 2.
1. Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project
Please link the Google Cloud Platform Project to the Google Apps Script Project of Spreadsheet "A". You can see the detailed steps at my repository.
2. Enable Apps Script API
Please enable Apps Script API at the API console.
3. Set scopes
Please set the following scopes for creating a container-bound script.

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects

If you want to use other scopes, also please include them.
4. Sample script
After the above steps are finished, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet "A". And please set the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet "B" to orgSpreadsheetId. In this sample, mainCode is modified. Please confirm it.
When you run mainCode, the Spreadsheet "B" is copied and the function scriptToBeAssigned is assigned to the button on the copied Spreadsheet "B". Then, a new container-bound script is created for the copied Spreadsheet "B" by the Apps Script API. By this, when you click the button on the copied Spreadsheet "B", the script of scriptToBeAssigned can be correctly run.
// Add a script of "scriptToBeAssigned" to the copied Spreadsheet.
function addBoundScriptToSpreadsheet_(spreadsheetId) {
  // Create a container-bound script to Google Spreadsheet.
  const baseUrl = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects";
  const headers = { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() };
  const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    baseUrl,
    {
      payload: JSON.stringify({ parentId: spreadsheetId, title: "sample project" }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers
    }
  );
  const { scriptId } = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());

  // Retrieve appsscript.json
  const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `${baseUrl}/${scriptId}/content`,
    {
      method: "get",
      headers
    }
  );
  const { files } = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
  const appsscript = files.find(({ name }) => name == "appsscript").source;

  // Copy the function "scriptToBeAssigned".
  const res3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `${baseUrl}/${scriptId}/content`,
    {
      method: "put",
      payload: JSON.stringify({
        files: [
          { type: "JSON", name: "appsscript", source: appsscript },
          { type: "SERVER_JS", name: "code", source: scriptToBeAssigned.toString() }
        ]
      }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers
    }
  );
  console.log(res3.getContentText())
}


// Please run this script.
function mainCode() {
  // Please set your original spreadsheet ID (Spreadsheet "B") and the sheet name including the button.
  const orgSpreadsheetId = "###";
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";

  // Copy the original Spreadsheet
  console.log("Copying the original Spreadsheet.");
  const orgFile = DriveApp.getFileById(orgSpreadsheetId);
  const copied = orgFile.makeCopy("copied spreadsheet").moveTo(orgFile.getParents().next());
  const images = SpreadsheetApp.open(copied).getSheetByName(sheetName).getImages();
  if (images.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("No image for a button.");
  }
  images[0].assignScript("scriptToBeAssigned");

  // Add script to the copied Spreadsheet.
  console.log("Copying the script 'scriptToBeAssigned' to the copied Spreadsheet.");
  addBoundScriptToSpreadsheet_(copied.getId());
}

// This is your script.
function scriptToBeAssigned() {
  // This is a simple sample script for testing. So, please replace this to your actual script.
  console.log("ok");
  Browser.msgBox("ok");
}

Additional information:
Here, when you want to change the script of scriptToBeAssigned and want to reflect the latest script by modifying it, in this case, when you modify scriptToBeAssigned and run mainCode, a new copied Spreadsheet "B" including the latest script is created.
If you want to use this as a library, it is required to prepare a script for copying to the copied Spreadsheet "B" and also modify the file of appsscript.json of the copied Spreadsheet "B". But, this might be a bit complicated. So, in this answer, I would like to omit about it.
References:

assignScript(functionName)
Method: projects.create
Method: projects.get
Method: projects.updateContent
Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE (Author: me)

